# Using self-defined functions in R to produce different random numbers Each time

Tags: r

I am trying to produce different uniform numbers using the Lehmar random number generator. I believe I have done this but I have a problem in producing different numbers each time I execute this function. Below is the code I am trying to do and I will explain the problem further underneath it.

```
            MODULUS <- 2147483647
            MULTIPLIER <- 48271

            put_Seed <- function(x)
            {
              x <- (if ( x > 0)
              {
                x%%MODULUS
              }
              else
              {
                1000*as.numeric(Sys.time())
              }
              )
            }

            T_val <- function(Rand)
            {
              Q <- floor(MODULUS / MULTIPLIER)
              R <- MODULUS%%MULTIPLIER;  

              floor(MULTIPLIER*(Rand%%Q) - R*(Rand/Q))
            }  

            New_Random_Seed <- function(T_value_i)
            {
              Random_Seed <- (if (T_value_i > 0)
              {
                T_value_i;
              }
              else
              {
                T_value_i + MODULUS
              })
            }

            Random <- function(New_Seed)
            {
              New_Seed/MODULUS
            }

            uniform_num <- function(a, b, r)
            {
              a + (b - a) * r
            }

            Random_Seed <- put_Seed(123456789)

            uni_num <- function(k)
            {

              Random_Seed <- put_Seed(k)
              T_value <- T_val(Random_Seed)
              Random_Seed <- New_Random_Seed(T_value)
              uniform_num(0, 1, Random(Random_Seed))

            }

            test1 <- uni_num(Random_Seed)
            test2 <- uni_num(Random_Seed)
            test3 <- uni_num(Random_Seed)

#Results
    #test1 = 0.05380306
    #test2 = 0.05380306
    #test3 = 0.05380306
```

What I am trying to do is whenever I run the uni_num function that each time, the Random_Seed gets updated and the uniform_num(0, 1, Random(Random_Seed)) line produces a random uniform number between 0 and 1 each time the function is executed. The code works for 1 repetition but if I try to use the function again the Random_Seed has not being updated and hence the function will produce the same random number as before. This is undesirable as I wish to produce different random number's each time by having the Random_Seed updated after each repetition. Forgive me if there is a simple solution but my head is wrecked from trying to find an answer. Cheers :)

Comment: short answer: change it to `Random_Seed <- putSeed(-123456789)` Secondly, why on earth would you split this into six separate functions?

Comment: If you are using the same value for the input `put_Seed` each time, that function will only return different values if it returns the `Sys.time` and that only happens when `x` is not > 0

Comment: Changing Random_Seed <- putSeed(-123456789) doesn't do anything. What I want is when I apply the uni_num(Random_Seed) line I get a different value each time I run it. The idea is that the Random seed should be updated within the function and thus uni_num(Random_Seed) should give a different value each time

Comment: Also I am using 6 functions initially as I find the problem personally easier to understand. Also how would you use the ifelse function to fix my problem.

Comment: I understand. No need to keep repeating yourself. I just copy/pasted your code yet again, only put in a negative, and it still works. clean your r session and try it again

Comment: For example, `put_Seed` could be changed to `put_Seed <- function(x) ifelse(x > 0, x %% MODULUS, 1000 * as.numeric(Sys.time()))`

Comment: Still doesn't work with or without the - in front of 123456789. I do appreciate the help.

Comment: Well I assume you're not changing `Random_Seed`. You need to rerun the line `Random_Seed <- put_Seed(-1)` each time you want a random generated. Otherwise you should expect the same result. Either source your code or change your last line to `uni_num(put_Seed(-1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function:

```
        uni_num <- function(k)
        {

          Random_Seed <- put_Seed(k)
          T_value <- T_val(Random_Seed)
          Random_Seed <- New_Random_Seed(T_value)
          uniform_num(0, 1, Random(Random_Seed))

        }
```

The target of the assignment `Random_Seed <-` is in the environment of the function body, and not the global environment.  Thus, when you make a second call, `Random_Seed` in the global environment has not been modified, and you get the same results.

To write to the global environment instead, use `<<-`:

```
Random_Seed <<- New_Random_Seed(T_value)
```

It looks like this is the only assignment that must be modified, as `New_Random_Seed` returns a value and doesn't require modification of this global object.  In addition, the first assignment to `Random_Seed` in `uni_num` might as well be in the function body environment.

Note that it's bad form for a function to write to the global environment.  There's always a better way.  But this will work for your example code.

Comment: Spot on @Matthew Lundberg, you're absolutely correct. I've never known about the <<- operator or about global versus function environment so I will learn about this. I admit the code is not the best so I will work to improve on it but your code is exactly what I was looking for. thank you so much for that :)